# Html javascript links include url variables in HTML 5 Boilerplate

Tags: javascript, html, caching, html5boilerplate

When I was looking at HTML 5 Boilerplate I noticed one thing: Almost every script link goes like this : **'../script.js?v=1'**. 
This 'v=1' part caught my attention so I did some research and found out that it is there for cache-ing purposes.
My question is : **How is this technique called and how is it done? Is there a way to change/ update version numbers automatically?**

Answer (score 0):

This is usually called a cachebusting URL.

If you change `script.js`, you can simply change it to `?v=2` to force the browser to skip the cache.  (because there is not cached content for `script.js?v-2`)

Most server-side web environments have plugins that can automatically generate cache-busting URLs, usually by including a hash of the file in the querystring.

Comment: But the question I am asking you is the following : How do I generate a new number only when I change the content of script.js.To be clear, I don't want to change that number whenever user makes a request to the server.

Comment: You have to change the number only if you change code in script.js. No worries about users making requests to the server.

Comment: @vanjadjurdjevic: You need to do that by hand by editing the HTML.